# Release note or changelog popup after extension upgraded

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, azure-stream-analytics

I developed an extension for VS Code helping users manage their services in Azure. I found that some of our extension users were not aware of the new features after the extension was upgraded. Is there a way to show extension's release note automatically e.g., a popup window or a new opening tab after users upgraded their extensions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (no more than 10-20 lines of code) you can do is (even if no VS Code API),

1. When the extension initializes, check if a file `SHOWED` is in the extension folder.
2. If not, pop up and notify your users of the release notes. These are typical functions in VS Code API.
3. After the notification, generate a zero length `SHOWED` file there.

Since every extension updates move to a new folder where no `SHOWED` file exists, your code can always notify the users with release notes again.

Comment: Let me try this out and get back to you. Thx